# Decimals are not recognized as numeric values in CodeEffects RuleEditor

Tags: c#, decimal, rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

When running a local version of the CodeEffects rule editor I get an error message when I try to enter a decimal in the condition. In the angular example project I have updated the type of the `pulse` property to `decimal?` and why I try to enter a decimal I get the following error message:

[image]

When I enter a dot instead of a comma it gets autocorrected to a dot. The current culture of my local machine is nl-nl as is my browser. When I run your live demo it works without any issues.

[image]

What is the issue when running this locally?

Comment: This sounds like you should be reporting the issue to Code Effects, not asking a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Code Effects requests on their website to post technical questions on StackOverflow. The accepted answer is given by the Code Effects customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the current culture to en-US before invoking your rule evaluation code on the server. Dealing with cultures in terms of numeric input is not an easy task. Instead of fighting with all possible use cases, devices, clients, and scenarios, we decided to simply convert all numeric delimiters into American dot. That way multicultured products can be run without unnecessary complexity. This change was introduced in version 4.x